# Push SQL Server output to Azure blob storage

Tags: sql-server, ssms, azure-blob-storage

Is there anyway I can fetch the SQL Server output to Azure blob storage?

I have a SQL query which returns certain Excel data, I want that Excel data to be redirected from SSMS to Azure blob storage.

I have created a job which runs that query every day and store the data on the same machine. But I want that data in Azure blob storage.

Comment: You can use [Azure data factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-factory/transform-data) to move data from local machine to Azure blob storage.